# hide sensitive code in a c++ project

Tags: c++, ip

I have a c++ project which commits to github, with many developers added as contributors. 
Some of the source code is quite sensitive in terms of IP...

Is there a way to hide some of the code from the project? The project needs that code to run, but the developers have no need to update ir or read it.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a curious question: What license is the whole project?

Comment: So you want to use others' contributions but not have them use yours?

Comment: We are not trying to hide other people's contributions at all. What I meant is that sometimes you need to give access to **your own code** to other developers. And you would like (as much as possible) to protect the re-distribution of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile the sensitive code into a dynamically linked library (.DLL on Windows), and only publish that plus the header file(s). Alternatively, compile it into a static library and require your other contributors to relink whenever it is updated.

Use standard techniques such as [Pimpl](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/024.htm) to ensure that your header file contains only interface and no implementation.

Note: a determined enough person can always figure out what your code is doing by disassembling it. However this method will prevent them from seeing the source code.

Comment: Yes, I guess that libraries might the only way. The annoying part is that you have to give one library per OS... It would be great if there was a way to have a repo (for example in github), which contained source code that other developers/contributors could use as part of the cloned project,  but some source code could not be read.

Comment: @mga What you are describing is impossible, because you said in the question, *"The project needs that code to run"*. This means that you must supply either readable source code, or compiled code. If some source code cannot be read (and you do not provide binaries), and the project needs that code to run, then nobody will be able to run the project.

Comment: I guess you are right. I was probably thinking of a magical way where the "sensitive code" in the project is obfuscated. So, humans cannot make any sense of it. But then, the project somehow de-obfuscates it when needed to compile and build...

Answer (score 1):

If you have any doubt about the licensing of the 'sensitive' code, you should not distribute it.

In terms of alternative routes, you could include binaries with the project instead. That way you can still use the code in your project by linking the binaries, but don't have to provide the source.

Comment: By binaries, do you mean a static library?